# SQL: Problem in selecting multiple tables with foreign key

Tags: mysql

### Problem

I didn't exactly as i want too..

### Target to happen

I want to make a transaction view for my database where the output will be:

### Tables

*Customer Table*
[image]

*Employee Table*
[image: Employee Table]

*Product Table*
[image: Product Table]

*Transaction Table*
[image: Transaction Table]

*Transaction Table*
[[image: Transaction Table]]

### Structure I want to happen:

[image: Click here to view]

### My SQL Query:

```
SELECT
  customer.CustomerName,
  transactions.TransactionID,
  transactions.Date,
  transactions.Type,
  transactions.Method,
  product.ProductName,
  product.Quantity,
  product.Price,
  employee.EmployeeName
FROM
  customer,
  transactions,
  product,
  employee
WHERE
   customer.CustomerID = transactions.TransactionID
```

### Query Output:

[image: Click here to view]

Comment: Please frame SQL questions with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: what do you mean.

Comment: im new  using this platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use proper joins (and aliases which are helpful).
The table `transactions` is linked to all 3 other tables via their foreign keys, so start the joins from it:

```
SELECT
  c.CustomerName,
  t.TransactionID,
  t.Date,
  t.Type,
  t.Method,
  p.ProductName,
  p.Quantity,
  p.Price,
  e.EmployeeName
FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN customer c ON c.CustomerID = t.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN product p ON p.ProductID = t.ProductID
INNER JOIN employee e ON e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
```

Comment: Thank you so much forpas, It works ! (View Output: https://i.imgur.com/iGEtvC3.jpg)

Comment: @MathewAgustinBella I edited the answer a few mins ago. I had a typo in an ON clause. Check the new code.

Comment: Instead of `ON c.CustomerID = t.TransactionID` write `ON c.CustomerID = t.CustomerID `

Comment: Yup i noticed that